# Is there a simple way to ETL from Azure Blob Storage to Snowflake EDW?

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, etl, azure-data-factory, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following ETL requirements for Snowflake on Azure and would like to implement the simplest possible solution because of timeline and technology constraints.

Requirements :

Load CSV data (only a few MBs) from Azure Blob Storage into Snowflake Warehouse daily into a staging table.
Transform the loaded data above within Snowflake itself where transformation is limited to just a few joins and aggregations to obtain a few measures. And finally, park this data into our final tables in a Datamart within the same Snowflake DB.
Lastly, automate the above pipeline using a schedule OR using an event based trigger (i.e. steps to kick in as soon as file lands in Blob Store).

Constraints :

We cannot use use Azure Data Factory to achieve this simplest design.
We cannot use Azure Functions to deploy Python Transformation scripts and schedule them either.
And, I found that Transformation using Snowflake SQL is a limited feature where it only allows certain things as part of COPY INTO command but does not support JOINS and GROUP BY. Furthermore, although the following THREAD suggests that scheduling SQL is possible, but that doesn't address my Transformation requirement.

Regards,
Roy

Attaching the following Idea diagram for more clarity.
[image: Design diagram for to implement the desired solution]

https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00009Z3O7hSAF/how-to-schedule-jobs-from-azure-cloud-for-loading-data-from-blobscheduling-snowflake-scripts-since-dont-have-cost-for-etl-tool-purchase-for-scheduling

[https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-transform.html#:~:text=Snowflake%20supports%20transforming%20data%20while,columns%20during%20a%20data%20load](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-transform.html#:%7E:text=Snowflake%20supports%20transforming%20data%20while,columns%20during%20a%20data%20load).

Answer (score 0):

You can create snowpipe on Azure blob storage, Once snowpipe created on top of your azure blob storage, It will monitor bucket and file will be loaded into your stage table as soon as new file comes in. After copied the data into stage table you can schedule transformation SQL using snowflake task.

You can refer snowpipe creation step for azure blob storage in below link:
[Snowpipe on microsoft Azure blob storage](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-auto-azure.html)

Comment: Hi Sriga, thanks for the idea let me check then.

Comment: If you don't need it to be real time then you can just use the COPY INTO functionality without having to wrap it in Snowpipe "code"